# Error when sending emails from Drone server (negative serial number in certificate)

Tags: email, ssl, certificate, drone.io

We're hosting our own Drone server and everything works fine except email. Our own server requires TLS so I've set it up to use port 587.

The error message we're getting each time an email is supposed to be sent is this:

`failed to parse certificate from server: x509: negative serial number`

No other systems or email clients connecting to the mail server complains about the certificate and the IT department has checked it's valid.

Comment: Just to clarify, have you checked that the serial number was not negative, or are you saying that other tools don't complain although it is indeed negative?

Comment: The serial is in hex and every online certificate tool I've tested says it's valid. But it's a known issue with go apparently... :-/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a bug (or disputed implementation) of the Go language: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8265

We can probably only hope for a bug fix for Go and then rebuild Drone.

Comment: If you can save that certificate (e.g. in PEM form), try to pass it to `openssl x509 -text -noout -in the_cert.pem`, this will show you the serial number. The [example from your link](http://play.golang.org/p/zpXKadV5mo) has indeed a negative serial number (-1). While it should be able to *parse* it, your implementation isn't necessarily wrong to reject it, since both RFC 3280 and RFC 5280 explicitly forbid negative serial numbers ("*serial numbers MUST be positive*"). I'd contact your IT department to ask them to get a certificate that is actually valid.

Comment: I'd say the fact that other validating tools don't fail is yet another example of why the [Robustness Principle ("*Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from other*")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) can actually be more damaging than helpful: it just punishes implementations that follow the spec, making them guess what they can or can't actually assume from that spec, while leaving non-compliant implementations free to spread. (To be fair, perhaps some implementations haven't moved from RFC 2459 to 3280/5280.)

Comment: What do you mean a "web CA"? I'd certainly get in touch with whoever supports this system.

Comment: I mean it's not a certificate issued by the IT department, it's obtained from GlobalSign. But yeah, they should fix their certificates.

Comment: Ah I see. I've seen CAs like this not following the specs, but since presumably your IT department at least paid for it, I would contact GloblaSign support and point them to RFC 3280 and RFC 5280. Are you sure you're indeed getting that certificate? There was a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25528516/372643) where such a certificate had in fact been generated by a deep inspection appliance / MITM proxy.